# When one Broker has a problem, what is the best way to resolve the situation?

Tags: apache-kafka

If I have three Brokers running in Kafka cluster,  and one of them failed due to an error.  So I only have two running brokers left.

- 1) Usually, when this happens, restarting a failed broker will solve the problem?
- 2) If restarting the broker wouldn't solve the problem, can I erase all the data that the failed Broker had and restart it? (Because all the data will be restored by two other Brokers).  Is this method okay in production?  If not, why?

When I was testing Kafka with my desktop on Windows 10 long time ago,  if a Broker has an error and the restarting the server wouldn't work, I erased all the data. Then, it began to run okay. (I am aware of Kafka and Windows issues.) So, I am curious if this would work on multi-clustered Kafka (Linux) environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, it depends what the error is. If it is a networking error, then there is nothing necessarily wrong with the logs, so you should leave them alone (unless they are not being replicated properly).

The main downside of deleting all data from a broker is that some topics may only have one replica, and it is on that node. Or if you lose other brokers while the replication is catching up, then all data is potentially gone. Also, if you have many TB of data that is replicating back to one node, then you have to be aware of any disk/network contention that may occur, and consider throttling the replication (which would take hours for the node to be healthy again)

But yes, Windows and Linux ultimately work the same in this regard, and it is one way to address a clustered environment